# Browser permission to retain file permission after refresh?

Tags: javascript, browser, file-permissions

Let's say that a user gives the browser permission to view/access a file. Then they refresh the page. Is there currently any mechanism to keep the permission to view that file afterwards? Here is an example in a database application showing what I mean:

https://www.loom.com/share/8b4d8b5b09384c8e90e3dbfca722b95f

I couldn't find any mention of it in [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Comment: Can there be file size limit? I mean like for your current requirement can the file size be very large?

Comment: It doesn't matter too much. For testing purposes the file can be 1KB or so (size doesn't matter).

Comment: There is no inbuilt mechanism to persist file access permissions through page refreshes in the File API AFAIK.

Comment: What you can do as a workaround is: **When the user selects a file, read the file content using the File API and store the file content in a client-side storage mechanism, such as `IndexedDB` or `LocalStorage`.** Now when the page gets refreshed, check the client-side storage for any stored file content. If file content is found in the storage, use it to display the file or perform any required operations, without asking the user for permission again.

Comment: The limitations as I mentioned will be on file size. This will not be efficient if the file size is very big.

Comment: @mandy8055 right, that might be a problem...but aside from that the browser doesn't have any permissions that would allow that (even if the user was prompted or whatever else they'd accept) ?

Comment: that's correct. Then the more robust approach would be to handle it at server side for persisting file access across sessions.  This would involve uploading the file to a server, where it can be stored and accessed later as needed, even after the user refreshes the page or closes the browser. This would require the user to grant permission to upload the file, but once the file is uploaded, you can manage access to the file on the server-side without any browser-imposed limitations.

Comment: Is simply asking for the permission at page load (but keep track of the actual chosen files) acceptable for your use case?

Comment: @Kaiido -- it could be, but what if the user added 5 files before refreshing the page? How could we bulk re-add those 5 files?

Comment: In that case that would be five prompts indeed. Could you clarify if you need to *read* the data as it was when the user selected it (hence copying it would be an option), to *read* the data that's accessible at the pointer at the time you access it (one request per handle), to let the user access and modify the data outside of your app (StorageManager wouldn't be an option) etc.? Would a solution implying asking access for a single common directory and then you provide the UI to navigate and select the files from there be an option?

Comment: @Kaiido could you explain that a bit more? What would happen with the StorageManager? Perhaps in an answer or so.

Comment: For an answer I think we need a more detailed question. The [StorageManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system) would allow you to copy the files in an origin private file system, maintaining the file system structure as you wish. However, your users won't be able to access that data outside of your app.